# What is root cause for exception "IllegalArgumentException: FlowConstruct cannot be null" in mule 3?

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am trying to execute an update statement and insert statement in a transaction in mule 3.9. I enclosed these 2 DB resources in a multi transaction component. when it try to deploy application i am getting following exception. But when I remove transactional component and have only 2 db resources component then I am not getting any deployment error and app runs fine. What is the reason for below error?

```
*Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: FlowConstruct cannot be null
at org.mule.processor.AsyncDelegateMessageProcessor.validateFlowConstruct(AsyncDelegateMessageProcessor.java:117) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.AsyncDelegateMessageProcessor.initialise(AsyncDelegateMessageProcessor.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.AbstractMuleObjectOwner.initialise(AbstractMuleObjectOwner.java:72) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.exception.AbstractExceptionListener.initialise(AbstractExceptionListener.java:164) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.AbstractMuleObjectOwner.initialise(AbstractMuleObjectOwner.java:72) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.exception.ChoiceMessagingExceptionStrategy.initialise(ChoiceMessagingExceptionStrategy.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.initialise(TransactionalInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:93) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.routing.AbstractSelectiveRouter.initialise(AbstractSelectiveRouter.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]
at org.mule.processor.chain.AbstractMessageProcessorChain.initialise(AbstractMessageProcessorChain.java:87) ~[mule-core-3.9.1.jar:3.9.1]*
```

***Error Code:***

```
    <choice doc:name="Master Switch">
        <when expression="#[(flowVars.MasterSwitch != null and flowVars.MasterSwitch.flag != null and flowVars.MasterSwitch.flag.DATA_VALUE.equalsIgnoreCase('Y'))]">
            <set-variable variableName="payloadCopy" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Original payload" />
            <flow-ref name="generate_unique_entity_id" doc:name="generate_unique_entity_id"/>
         
            <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="HistCreatedDate" value="#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS')]"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistoryId" value="#[flowVars.uniqueEntityId]"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistLastUpdatedDt" value="#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS')]"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistChannelId" value="${hist_channel_id}"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistAppId" value="${hist_app_id}"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>

                    <set-variable variableName="lastIndicator" value="Y" doc:name="lastIndicator column value"/>
                    <ee:multi-transactional action="ALWAYS_BEGIN" doc:name="Transactional">
                        <db:update config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration"  doc:name="Database" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN">
                            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[${x_hist_update}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                        </db:update>
                        <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration"  doc:name="x_hist" transactionalAction="ALWAYS_JOIN">
                            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[${x_hist_insert}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                        </db:insert>
                    </ee:multi-transactional>

            <set-payload value="#[flowVars.payloadCopy]" doc:name="Payload before Flow" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="${logger.info} --- Skipping flow as the master switch is turned off." level="INFO" category="appinfologger" doc:name="Switch off logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(java.lang.Exception)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
             <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" category="appinfologger" message="${logger.info} - x hist transaction failed"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

***Working Code:***

```
    <choice doc:name="Master Switch">
        <when expression="#[(flowVars.MasterSwitch != null and flowVars.MasterSwitch.flag != null and flowVars.MasterSwitch.flag.DATA_VALUE.equalsIgnoreCase('Y'))]">
            <set-variable variableName="payloadCopy" value="#[payload]" doc:name="Original payload" />
            <flow-ref name="generate_unique_entity_id" doc:name="generate_unique_entity_id"/>
         
            <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
                <add-message-property key="HistCreatedDate" value="#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS')]"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistoryId" value="#[flowVars.uniqueEntityId]"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistLastUpdatedDt" value="#[server.dateTime.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSSSSS')]"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistChannelId" value="${hist_channel_id}"/>
                <add-message-property key="HistAppId" value="${hist_app_id}"/>
            </message-properties-transformer>

                    <set-variable variableName="lastIndicator" value="Y" doc:name="lastIndicator column value"/>
                    
                        <db:update config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration"  doc:name="Database" >
                            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[${x_hist_update}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                        </db:update>
                        <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration"  doc:name="x_hist" >
                            <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[${x_hist_insert}]]></db:parameterized-query>
                        </db:insert>
                    

            <set-payload value="#[flowVars.payloadCopy]" doc:name="Payload before Flow" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <logger message="${logger.info} --- Skipping flow as the master switch is turned off." level="INFO" category="appinfologger" doc:name="Switch off logger"/>
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <choice-exception-strategy doc:name="Choice Exception Strategy">
        <catch-exception-strategy when="#[exception.causedBy(java.lang.Exception)]" doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
             <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" category="appinfologger" message="${logger.info} - x hist transaction failed"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </choice-exception-strategy>
</flow>
```

Comment: Please add the flow around those components and any extra lines in the error message.

Comment: sure, i will add it now.

Comment: Added full flow and error details

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I was not using any catch strategy for transaction component. Therefore it is referring default exception handling strategy defined in my application. That strategy doesn't have any associated flow construct. To fix, I created catch exception strategy for transaction component and it works fine.